# Guardar checkbox array en variable javascript y mandarlo a php por GET

Tags: php, javascript, html, array

El boton ejecuta la funcion

```
<form name="mandararray">
<input  type="text" id="atencion" value="<? echo $atencion;?>"/>
<input  type="text"  id="cotiza">
//checkbox esta dentro de un while
<input type="checkbox" name="for2[]" value="<? echo $row["id"];?>">
//end while
<button type="submit" onClick="compra();">Orden de compra</button>
</form>
```

en la funcion se guardan los valores por medio de id, pero no logro guardar los datos dentro del array en la variable for2.
lo que falla es guardar los datos del checkbox en la variable for2

```
function compra(){
     //-------------------------------------------------// 
     var for2 = document.mandararray.elements[“for2[]”];
     //-------------------------------------------------// 
     var cotiza = $("#cotiza").val(); 
     var provid = $("#provid").val(); 
     var atencion = $("#atencion").val(); 
     var empresa = $("#empresa").val(); 
     VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/ordendecompra_pdf.php?cotiza='+cotiza+'&for2='+for2+'&atencion='+atencion+'&empresa='+empresa+'&provi d='+provid,'Cotizacion','','1024','768','true'); 
    };
```

la funcion manda las variables cotiza, empresa etc. a un archvivo que genera un pdf con los valores mandados.
pero no logro que mande los valores del array for2[]

Comment: Deberias editar tu pregunta, y plantear una pregunta mas especifica acerca de un error especifico para poder darte una solución especifica. Explica el codigo que tienes y lo que quieres hacer, y el error o donde te encuentras atascado, pero no puedes pedir que hagan o te den todo hecho ya que lo mas seguro que esta pregunta acabe cerrada

Comment: lo siento soy nuevo aqui lo intentare

Comment: Una parte es como generas el HTML (parte PHP) y otra como los recoges y los envías al servidor (parte JS). Ve paso por paso para determinar lo que te falla: ¿ésta mal el HTML generado? ¿no puedes generar el HTML con los checkboxes? ¿falla el JS a la hora de recoger los valores? ¿al enviarlos?

Comment: si el js no recoge los valores del checkbox